# narrowing the type of array elements is working with variable but not index

Tags: typescript

```
type Soccer = { ball: string }
type Basketball = { jump: string }
type Data = Soccer[] | Basketball[]

if ('ball' in data[index]) { // type guard does not work here.
  <MyComponent something={data[index]} /> // data: Soccer[] | Basketball[]
}
```

```
const resultObj = data[index] // indexed element is assigned to variable.

if ('ball' in resultObj)
  <MyComponent resultObj={resultObj} /> // works with variable
```

```
if (data)
  <MyComponent resultObj={data[index]} /> // not works with index.
```

I don't understand how assigning `data[index]` to variable solved the type narrowing issue.
I expected `'ball' in data[index]` would work. But it did not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type narrowing does not work if the index is not a literal (I reckon that `index` in your example is of type `number`).

Your best workaround is what you're already doing: assign the value of `data[index]` to a variable and narrow that down.

---

See more here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530